# How to create media query with max width?

Tags: html, css, wordpress, responsive-design

I have a Wordpress with Boss 2.0 theme installed and a custom header I want to hide on mobile device and only show it on desktop 720px or wider.

I created `<div class="container" id="custom-header">`

and in my CSS file i did:

```
@media screen and (max-width: 720px) {
 /* Remove Header for phone portrait */
 #custom-header {
  display: none;
  }
}
```

Obviously it doesn't work, but if I try the opposite:

```
@media screen and (min-width: 720px) {
/* Remove Header for phone portrait */
#custom-header {
 display: none;
 }
}
```

It work perfectly hiding my header when I stretch my window more than 720px.

First reflex was to add `display: none !important;` but no better results.

Any solutions for hiding my content on device less than 720px wide?

Comment: Can you inspect element the css and see what specific "display" affect `#custom-header`?

Comment: It works fine here: https://jsfiddle.net/Hunter377/ogjpjp0b/ You may have some conflicting styles.

Comment: it should be visiable for more than 720 and hide if lesser than 720px right !

Comment: Yes : visible for more than 720px hidden for less ( the opposite of your jsfiddle @HunterTurner )

Comment: No. If you look at my fiddle, it does exactly as you describe. If you make the result box larger than 720px, you will see the div appear.

Answer (score 0):

probably your "custom-header" is inheriting another css,  check it on style elements of your developer tool (f12 in  major browsers)

**another thing you should see is the cascade declaration in mediaQuerys**
if your using max-width, rembeber  declarate them from higher to lower .

With min-width from lower to higher.

Hope works for you

Comment: I have this in my inspector when I reduce my window in a grey block that I can't edit in chrome inspector styles section :   div {       user agent stylesheet
    display: block;
}

Answer (score 0):

i am not sure about how you tried reducing to 720px. Try by toggling the device mode that are available in google chrome developer tool.

Comment: Well my logic is if I can make work the inverse of how I want it to react, it should work exactly as I want, but it doesn't. I used my navigator reducung it's size and also a chrome plugins that simulate any device format I want. Nothing work so far.

Answer (score 0):

You can try

```
@media all and (max-width: 720px) {
 /* Remove Header for phone portrait */
 #custom-header {
  display: none !important;
  }
}
```

Adding media all you will see the css change in your pC

Answer (score -1):

Try this way

```
@media (min-width: 320px) and (max-width: 720px) {
#custom-header {
 display: none;
 }
}
```

Comment: Nope, still won't hide : (